# TTY switch with one external hardware button (cycle)

Tags: tty

Is there any method to use a script that can be activated from external button to switch betwen TTY's?
I have a small home controll Raspberry with LCD screen on it, i dont have a keyboard or mouse attached to it and i have several buttons next to LCD mapped to do comands like reboot, etc. I want to have a one of those buttons programmed that on a keypress it will switch to another (next) tty, and go back to tty1 on a end of "cycle". I know `chvt` and keyboard combinations with `Alt F1, F2...`but non of them work as i want to. Is it possible ??
The clue is to have three (or more) programs (like a diagnostics) on different tty's to look when accessing my "rack" :)

Comment: The 'button' would need to send a signal to the Raspberry, through terminal emulation into a USB port or some other interface. Therefore, there's got to be some infrastructure under that button. What interface and what logic are you going to use?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write a program like `chvt` that cycles through the KVTs, and connect it up like you have (you say) already connected other programs to other buttons.

On FreeBSD:

- The currently active KVT number is available as the output of `vidcontrol -i active`.
- The "next" action is `vidcontrol -s $NEXT` after an increment and some modulo arithmetic.

On NetBSD:

- The currently active KVT number is available as the output of `wsconscfg -g`.
- The "next" action is `wsconscfg -s $NEXT` after an increment and some modulo arithmetic.

On Linux:

- The currently active KVT number is available in a pseudo-file under `/sys/class/tty`.
- The "next" action is `chvt $NEXT` after an increment and some modulo arithmetic.
- The maximum possible KVT number is fixed (and you can always hardwire a lower maximum according to your needs).

On all three, all of the above could be done with some simple shell script arithmetic.  Or you could write a program in another language, to make the underlying `ioctl()` calls (`VT_GETACTIVE` and `VT_ACTIVATE` on FreeBSD for example) directly.

OpenBSD requires such programming to call the `wsdisplay`(4) `ioctl()`s directly, as there are no handy utilities for this.

User-space virtual terminals, rendered directly onto a framebuffer, may have similar mechanisms, varying according to software.  Mine, for example, responds to the actual USB HID codes for the "consumer device application launch" *next/previous task* keys.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[linux-vt](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml)".  *Devices*.  nosh toolset.
- Soren Schmidt et al. (2016-01-19). [`vidcontrol`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vidcontrol).  *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*.
- [`wsconscfg`](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wsconscfg). *NetBSD System Manager's Manual*.  2006-06-24.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`console-multiplexor`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-multiplexor.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`console-multiplexor-control`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-multiplexor-control.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.